# Javascript animation only filling half of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a new animation background to my website (but in no means was designed by me, however I got permission from the author to use on mine) and want to also edit it to suit my tastes and that is where my first roadblock happens. I added the neccesary code from a github repo which allows me to add this cool hyperspace warpspeed animation to the background of my website but when viewing, it only shows half of the animation however I would like to have it fill the whole screen. I am suspecting that this is coming from my css however I am very new to web development and I have been learning, I can do little edits here and there on html but not css so if someone could interpret this I would really appreciate it.

This is part of my index:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>removed</title>
  <script src="js/warpspeed.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="description" content="removed">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Browser Theming for Chrome, Firefox, Opera + Windows Phone + iOS Safari-->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#37383F">
  <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#37383F">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#37383F">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body onload="EasterEgg()">
<div style="position:fixed; z-index:0; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">new WarpSpeed("canvas");</script>
</div>
```

And here is my css, I have put everything as I do not know which part is relevant to the half screen issue:

```
/*
==========================

        BASE

==========================
*/

canvas {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Roboto Mono;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
==========================
        MAIN
==========================
*/

.boxcontainer {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  z-index: 10;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  animation:slide 0.8s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#dirbox {
  display: none;
}

img {
  height: 128px;
  width: auto;
}

.title {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin:  10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.desc {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin:  10px 0;
  color: #808080;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.link {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin:  10px 0;
  color: #808080;
  transition: filter 0.2s ease, transform 0.4s ease;
}

.link:hover {
  filter: brightness(.6);
}

.linkcont {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  transition: filter 0.2s ease, transform 0.4s ease;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;

}

.linksquare {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.linksquare:hover {
  filter: brightness(.6);
}

svg {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  fill: #7f7f7f;
  padding: 10px;
}
.clickable {pointer-events: none}
.unclickable {pointer-events: auto; user-select: none; -moz-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none;}
/*
==========================
        ANIM
==========================
*/

@keyframes slide {
  0% {transform: translate(0, 2.5em); opacity: 0;}
  100% {transform: translate(0, 0); opacity: 1;}
}
```

Any help would be appreicated, I am very sorry if anything I say sounds dumb as I am sort of a beginner to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "position:absolute;" from your CSS (.canvas).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :)